# MariaDB doesn't set authentication_string during installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb, security, mariadb-10.3

I'm setting up a new server using MariaDB (current stable version of 10.3) and I notice that all of my users - mainly root and debian-sys-maint - do not have an `authentication_string` after the installation is done, even after running `mysql_secure_installation`.

I'm about to re-install my server again and wondering how do I set all my users to get an `authentication_string` during the installation? And if that isn't possible, would it cause problems if I set a password to debian-sys-maint user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike newer versions of MySQL (5.7+), MariaDB doesn't seem to use the `authentication_string` of the `user` table for normal passwords when using the default plugin (i.e. `mysql_native_password`). Instead, the passwords are found in the `password` column, like in older versions of MySQL.

However, you can get something into the `authentication_string` if you create a user using e.g. the `pam` plugin:

```
CREATE USER u1@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA pam USING 'mariadb';
```

(`authentiation_string` now contains 'mariadb' in plaintext for this user, though this is not the password, just a reference to a PAM configuration file. With PAM the password is no longer stored in MariaDB.)

Comment: During installation, when I enter a password for the `root` user, does `debian-sys-maint` use the same password for `root`?

Comment: @GregorySchultz I don't think so. The debian-sys-maint user's credentials found in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`, so you can verify for yourself.